# crystal report - page footer overlaps details section

Tags: crystal-reports, report, footer

I have a report with two header sections (***HS***), two details sections (***DS***) and two page footer sections (***PFS***).

and I want to get report with following layout

page 1:

***HS-1
DS-1 
PFS-1***

page 2 and more:

***HS-2 
DS-2 
PFS-2***

and I do it but my problem is with first page, ***PFS-1*** overlaps ***DS-1***.
***DS-1*** has **"new page after"** condition where after one record is displayed new page should start. ***HS-1*** and ***PFS-1*** are suppressed `if pagenumber <> 1`

there are text boxes and line objects on ***DS-1*** but PFS-1 overlaps almost half of it while the PFS-1 itself is just one line in size.

PFS-1 is **"fit section"** and no, I can't use

> print at bottom of page

because it is disabled, grayed out. as for sizes of section they are same as the second ones but I have no problem with second or farther pages, this problem occurs only on first page.

as you can see in picture below, text marked with red is the single line of footer and it is way too high positioned and it overlaps the details section :/.
under that footer there is at least one more box like the one that is outlined with blue box and three data fields .

[image]

please can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I am sorry but couldn't understand what are you trying to explain

Comment: my page footer section overlaps details section,
page footer section is almost in the middle of report instead of its original, bottom place.
non of the sections are too big to say that it is because of the section sizes.  I am working in visual studio 2008 and CR is 2008 as well

Comment: You have to create the two sub report. Display this two sub report on the main report so that your problem will get solve.